# Why sudo python and python in terminal start two different versions python?

Tags: python, sudo

I had python 2.6 in my server to begin with. Then I downloaded python 2.7 and installed using make and make altinstall. When I try just python in the terminal it opens up python 2.7 but sudo python opens up 2.68. all the commands like virtualenv pip use python 2.68

Comment: Probably because `$PATH` differs between you and root.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `sudo XYZ` basically means "run XYZ as some other user (root by default)".  That user may have a different set of environment variables, including `$PATH`.

To confirm this, compare the output of the following:

```
env | grep PATH
sudo env | grep PATH
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the case. How do I ensure the path are same?

Answer (score 2):

The python Version of user:

```
~> python --version
Python 3.6.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

The python version of SUDO:

```
~> sudo python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

**If you want to execute the same version of python when using sudo, you may try:**

```
~> sudo env "PATH=$PATH" python --version
Python 3.6.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Comment: how to make those changes permanent?

Answer (score 0):

Check the outputs of `which python` and `sudo which python`, they should be different. If so, check your `$PATH` for root and your normal user as noted by others.

Answer (score 0):

As was suggested, check your path. If that does not work, check your `.bashrc` in your home directory. A standard way to use a different python version is to use an alias for python (assigned to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` for example) in the `.bashrc`