# How to add/modify PATH for sudo?

Tags: linux, python, sudo

I have installed two versions of Python.

- Python 2.7.14 in `/usr/local/bin`
- Python 2.7.5 in `/usr/bin`.

When I type `# python`, it uses version `2.7.14` but when I type `sudo python`, it uses version `2.7.5`. How can I make `sudo python` point to version `2.7.14`?

In the output of `sudo env | grep PATH`, `/usr/local/bin` appears before `/usr/bin` but still it is picking up Python from `/usr/bin`.

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

When I type `sudo su` to enter into the root shell, it gives me `python 2.7.14` but in the same session if I type `sudo python`, it gives me `python 2.7.5`.

I went through [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/600349/why-sudo-python-and-python-in-terminal-start-two-different-versions-python/1276417#1276417) but the accepted answer doesn't answer how to ensure sudo uses the correct path.

Here is how the secure path looks like:

```
secure_path = /usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: What's output of `sudo type python`? (I suspect that you aliased `python` to something else, or created a function somewhere.)

Comment: @Franklin that doesn't work for me. Says `sudo: type: command not found
`. I did create an alias but I removed it because it was not working for sudo

Comment: All right, how about `sudo bash -c 'type python'`?

Comment: @Franklin it outputs `python is /bin/python`

Comment: What OS are you using? Is Bash the log-in shell for root, or some other shell?

Comment: how about `sudo env python`?

Comment: `sudo env python` outputs 2.7.5.  I am using RHEL 7.4. So sudo is picking up python from `/bin/python`. Now how do I make it point to `/usr/local/bin/python`.  I update the question to show how does my `secure path` inside `/etc/sudoers` looks like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71380/discussion-between-manoj-and-franklin-yu).

Comment: How about `secure_path="/usr/local/bin:..."` (no spaces)? Then maybe you need to reload: `sudo service sudo force-reload` (or whatever works in your distro).

Answer (score 1):

Edited because sudo does not automatically launch a shell (as per Dave Thompson's comment), to fix readability, and to add information.

This is definitely a `sudo` and `GNU/Linux` question, not a `Python` question.

When you run `sudo foo arg1 arg2` it is not exactly the same as logging in as `root` and typing `foo arg1 arg2` on the command line. Note that there are executables that will not allow a sudo-ed user to run or do some things and that environment variables will not be the same as the environment from where you used `sudo`. Some are added (e.g., `SUDO_COMMAND`, `SUDO_USER`, etc.), some will be missing entirely, and some will be modified. You can see what is different by running `diff <(env) <(sudo env)`

You can preserve most of the variables from the shell from which you ran `sudo` by using the `--preserve-env` flag.

Additionally, the `my_user` bash shell will do alias expansion on the first item (i.e., the **sudo** in `sudo foo arg1 arg2`) and not the second (**foo**). So if `foo` is also an alias, it will not be expanded and therefore the subprocess running as `root` will try to run `foo` as a literal, and not `foo` as the alias you created under `my_user`. The easiest way to "fix" your issue is to define an alias for `sudo` with a trailing space:

```
    alias='sudo '
```

As explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22037/aliases-not-available-when-using-sudo), this will cause what comes after `sodo` to be alias-expanded as well  **before** sending it to the subshell to run.

Comment: This is wrong (except for the alias-space fix for an alias, which does not appear to apply to the Q). `sudo` does NOT run a shell unless (1) you tell it to do so explicitly e.g. `sudo bash -c 'foo'` or you tell it to run something like `su` that in turn runs a shell (as Q did) or (2) you use `-i` (which Q didn't).